# How do I make an arrow shaped button with css?

Tags: css, button

I want to make a button that looks something like the image below, left and right, but all I achieved was a simple triangle pointing the directions. Can someone help me?

[image of arrow mentioned on the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUyMl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first html code And after css code

```css
.click{
    padding: 10px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
  <body>
<a href="Your link for after click">
<button class="click">  </button>
</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use font awesome icon inside a button
https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons/angles-right?s=solid

```css
button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4tMg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body>
  <button><i class="fa-solid fa-angles-right"></i></button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use unicode character like `» and «`

more chars

https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrow-symbols/

http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_arrows.html

```css
button,
li {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '» ➫ ➾';
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>button ➵</button>

<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the character based options in the other answers, you can also make an arrow shape, or any other shape, for your button by using a background image. First of course default styling is removed such as background color and border.

To make styling easier, any text is inside a `div` (**#buttontext**) within the button tag. The **CSS** `:active` selector is used to change the image when the button is "pressed." A minor JavaScript effect is added just to suggest further experimentation.

```js
function clickFx() {
document.getElementById("buttontext").style.color="white";
}
```

```css
button {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

button.arr {
  width: 20em;
  height: 16em;
  background-size: 60% 50%;
  background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUyMl.png");
}

button.arr:active {
  background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/v5FkWV7.png");
}
 
button.sub {
  width: 16em;
  height: 6em;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/YHo3sNu.jpg");
  background-size: 90% 80%;
  }

button.sub:active {
  background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/hdqKzPb.jpg");
}
  
#buttontext {
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 1em;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="arr"><div id="buttontext"></div>
</button>

<button type="submit" class="sub" onclick="clickFx()"><div id="buttontext">
More Button</div>
</button>
```